# Group where Out(G) acts differently on conjugacy classes and irreps?

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, finite-groups

$\def\Conj{\mathrm{Conj}}\def\Irrep{\mathrm{Irrep}}\def\Out{\mathrm{Out}}$Let $G$ be a finite group, let $\Conj(G)$ be the set of conjugacy classes of $G$, let $\Irrep(G)$ be the set of isomorphism classes of complex irreps of $G$ and let $\Out(G)$ be the outer automorphism group of $G$. Then $\Out(G)$ acts on both the sets $\Irrep(G)$ and $\Conj(G)$. (Since $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$ acts in an obvious way, and the inner automorphisms act trivially.)

The permutation representations $\mathbb{C}^{\Irrep(G)}$ and $\mathbb{C}^{\Conj(G)}$ are isomorphic (because evaluation of characters gives a perfect pairing between them, and both representations, being permutation representations, are self dual). Is there a group where the sets $\Conj(G)$ and $\Irrep(G)$ don't have an $\Out(G)$-equivariant bijection?

Comment: I feel like this is a duplicate of a question from MO's early days but I can't find it.

Comment: [This one?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/21606/orbit-structures-of-conjugacy-class-set-and-irreducible-representation-set-under?rq=1)

Comment: Yup! That's the one, thanks.

Comment: There's certainly a way to modify this interesting question to make it not redundant with the previous one?

Comment: @YCor Probably, but the answers to that question seem pretty thorough.

Comment: Related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/393934/are-there-always-more-conjugacy-classes-in-the-kernel-of-a-morphism-to-z-2-tha/393938#393938